# Is it possible to create an object context dynamically

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

With the entity framework, the ObjectContext is created from a config file:

```
ObjectContext ctx = new ObjectContext ("name=testEntities", "testEntities")
```

Is it possible to create the object context entirely in code, without a config file?

If so, how do you specify the CDSL, SSCL and MSL?

Answer (score 2):

Sure; just pass a full, valid EF connection string in the constructor, rather than a connection string name.

Comment: Hi Graig, Thank you for your reply. Can one create the different schemas in code?

Comment: Yes, but it's a heck of a lot easier to do it with Code First (EF 4.1)